# Stim : How to use gates multiplied by a constant or how to convert between Y and XZ

Tags: stim

The usual convention is that $Y=\imath XZ$ let's call that the "complex" $Y$ convention; for a number of reasons I prefer to work with $Y=XZ$, the "real" $Y$ convention. Stim works with the complex $Y$ convention; how would I do a $CY$ and $MPP$ in the real convention? I can find workarounds by multiplying by $\imath$ but I didn't see in the documentation how that's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CAUTION: MEASURING iY IS NOT PROJECTIVE BECAUSE iY IS NOT HERMITIAN**

If you measure Y, you [project into a state and stay there](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22Amps3%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22Y%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22ZDetectControlReset%22%5D%2C%5B%22Amps3%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22Y%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22ZDetectControlReset%22%5D%2C%5B%22Amps3%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22Y%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22ZDetectControlReset%22%5D%2C%5B%22Amps3%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22Y%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22ZDetectControlReset%22%5D%2C%5B%22Amps3%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22Y%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22ZDetectControlReset%22%5D%2C%5B%22Amps3%22%5D%5D%2C%22gates%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Epepq%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22iY%22%2C%22circuit%22%3A%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22i%22%5D%2C%5B%22Y%22%5D%5D%7D%7D%5D%7D):

[image: project and stay]

If you measure iY (to the extent that this can be given a meaningful interpretation, since it's not Hermitian), [you drift around](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22Amps3%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22%7Epepq%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22ZDetectControlReset%22%5D%2C%5B%22Amps3%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22%7Epepq%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22ZDetectControlReset%22%5D%2C%5B%22Amps3%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22%7Epepq%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22ZDetectControlReset%22%5D%2C%5B%22Amps3%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22%7Epepq%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22ZDetectControlReset%22%5D%2C%5B%22Amps3%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22%7Epepq%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%8A%96%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22ZDetectControlReset%22%5D%2C%5B%22Amps3%22%5D%5D%2C%22gates%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22%7Epepq%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22iY%22%2C%22circuit%22%3A%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22i%22%5D%2C%5B%22Y%22%5D%5D%7D%7D%5D%7D):

[image: drift]

Assuming *that's actually what you want*, read on...

---

Stim doesn't have `CiY` or `MPP iY` as native operations. You will have to decompose them into operations that Stim does support.

You can decompose a controlled-$iY$ into a $CY$ followed by an $S$ on the control.

```
# perform CiY 0 1
CY 0 1
S 0
```

Perhaps more natural is to decompose it into CX*CZ:

```
# perform CiY 0 1
CX 0 1
CZ 0 1
```

You can decompose an `MPP iY` into controlled Pauli operations onto a clean ancilla. You apply an S gate to that ancilla for each of the factors of $i$ you accumulated. So, if the number of factors of $i$ is 1 mod 4, apply S. For 2 mod 4 apply Z. For 3 mod 4 apply S_DAG. For 0 mod 4 do nothing. You then get the measurement result via a demolition measurement of the ancilla.

```
# perform MPP X0*iY1*Z2
R 999  # clean ancilla
XCX 0 999
YCX 1 999
ZCX 2 999
S 999  # this accounts for the `i` in `iY`
MR 999
```

Again, it's perhaps more natural to decompose into CX and CZ, as this avoids the need to manually do the S gates:

```
# perform MPP X0*iY1*Z2
R 999  # clean ancilla
XCX 0 999 1 999
ZCX       1 999 2 999
# factor of i accounted for by X*Z from qubit 1
MR 999
```